# Buttons do not appear as they should even if they're formatted in CSS file

Tags: html, css

So i got to a website that builds buttons in css, created my button and now im tryin to integrate it into my code. However, they just appear as plain text. 
I mean that if i open my html page i just see them in the top left corner as simple text, no format, no border, no box, nothing

```css
.button_rock {
  /* generated code */
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
   -moz-border-radius: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Open Sans;
   font-size: 60px;
   font-weight: 400;
   padding: 31px;
   background-color: #1683FF;
   box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   border: outset #0059A0 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
  /*=================*/


}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="button_rock">Rock</a>
      <a href="#" class="button_paper">Paper</a>
      <a href="#" class="button_scissors">Scissors</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: https://karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans

Comment: Seems likely that you haven't linked the CSS file correctly.

Comment: i did because my background works

Comment: Hi, I edited your raw code using stackoverflow code snippet tool. See how it works.

Comment: YES IT WORKED! I ll just follow your model and solve all of em, thank you!!

Comment: @GabrielPieptea Stackoverflow code snippet tool is good but not for testing. If you want to write tests (HTML, CSS, JS), use [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). If my comment was helpful, at least please upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button_rock {
  /* generated code */
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
   -moz-border-radius: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Open Sans;
   font-size: 60px;
   font-weight: 400;
   padding: 31px;
   background-color: #1683FF;
   box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: -13px -11px 33px 0px #000000;
   border: outset #0059A0 0px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
  /*=================*/


}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#" class="button_rock">Rock</a>
      <a href="#" class="button_paper">Paper</a>
      <a href="#" class="button_scissors">Scissors</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```